# Integrate an inequality

Tags: analysis

Suppose, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\lVert y\rVert^2\leq -\frac{M}{2}\lVert y\rVert^2+O\left(e^{-Kt}\right)
$$
for $t$ large enough and some $M,K>0$.

(Here $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the $L^2$-norm.)

It is said that integrating this inequality gives
$$
\lVert y\rVert\leq Ce^{-\nu t}
$$
for some $C,\nu>0$.

I am not sure how I can integrate the inequality in order to get the claimed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $x:=\Vert y\Vert^2$ so we want to prove $\dot{x}\le -Mx+O(e^{-Kt})\implies x\le C^2e^{-2\nu t}$. Now define $z:=xe^{Mt}$ so we want to prove $\dot{z}\le O(e^{(M-K)}t)\implies z\le C^2e^{(M-2\nu)t}$.

Expansive edit: since $\dot{z}=(\dot{x}+Mx)e^{Mt}\le O(e^{(M-k)}t)$, positive constants $A,\,B$ exist with $z\le A+Be^{(M-K)t}$. This is $\le C^2e^{(M-2\nu)t}$ provided$$C^2\ge Ae^{(2\nu-M)t}+Be^{(2\nu-K)t}.$$But any function of $t$ of this form with $0<\nu<\frac12\min\{M,\,K\}$ will have an upper bound we can find by calculus, so just make $C^2$ the square root of this supremum.

Comment: @Rhjg Using $\dot{z}=(\dot{x}+Mx)e^{Mt}$.

Comment: @Rhjg For which $\nu$ does $ze^{(2\nu-M)t}$ have a finite upper bound at some $z>0$?

Comment: @Rhjg Right! For such a $\nu$, you can force $ze^{(2\nu-M)t}\le C^2$ for a sufficiently large $C>0$. (In a previous comment, my $z>0$ should have read $t>0$.)

Comment: @Rhjg See edit.

Comment: To get $z\leq A+Be^{(M-K)t}$ you are using that $\vert\dot{z}\rvert =\dot{z}\leq De^{(M-K)t}$ for some constant $D>0$ and $t$ sufficiently large; then you just integrate, i.e. $\int \dot{z}\, dt=z\leq D\int e^{(M-K)t}\, dt=D(\frac{1}{M-K}e^{(M-K)}t + const)=: A+Be^{(M-K)t}$. Right?